# Pseudo-tensor- and tensor-densities: Sections of what bundle?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, vector-bundles, multilinear-algebra, tensor

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a smooth manifold. A tensor field is then usually defined to be a section of the tensor bundle
$$\bigotimes_{i=1}^{p}T\mathcal{M}\otimes\bigotimes_{i=1}^{q}T^{\ast}\mathcal{M}.$$

In physics, tensor fiels are normally defined using their transformation property. Usually, one then defines also ``(pseudo-)tensor densities'' by adding a factor to the transformation rule.

I was not able to find any global or abstract definition of such objects. I would like to know, how the concept of tensor densities is defined using similarely to tensor field the notion of vector bundles. Does anyone have some literature for such discussion?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I think (at least) one point of view is that of "natural vector bundles".  This is a vector bundle with extra structure.  For instance, see some of the responses to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2420241/tangent-bundle-of-a-manifold-as-more-than-a-vector-bundle

Comment: “Density” usually refers to something you want to integrate over a space. A scalar density is an exterior $n$-tensor or it’s absolute value (which is not  tensor). So a tensor density sound like the tensor product of a tensor with a scalar density.